# How to inject a repository into a service in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I need to inject two objects into `ImageService`. One of them is an instance of `Repository/ImageRepository`, which I get like this:

```
$image_repository = $container->get('doctrine.odm.mongodb')
    ->getRepository('MycompanyMainBundle:Image');
```

So how do I declare that in my services.yml? Here is the service:

```
namespace Mycompany\MainBundle\Service\Image;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentRepository;

class ImageManager {
    private $manipulator;
    private $repository;

    public function __construct(ImageManipulatorInterface $manipulator, DocumentRepository $repository) {
        $this->manipulator = $manipulator;
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }

    public function findAll() {
        return $this->repository->findAll();
    }

    public function createThumbnail(ImageInterface $image) {
        return $this->manipulator->resize($image->source(), 300, 200);
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a peek at http://blog.code4hire.com/2011/08/custom-repository-with-dic-in-symfony2/

Comment: @simshaun Thanks, that helped me to find how to do it in yml: http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/dependency_injection/factories.html

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I found this [link](http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/dependency_injection/factories.html) and this worked for me:

```
parameters:
    image_repository.class:            Mycompany\MainBundle\Repository\ImageRepository
    image_repository.factory_argument: 'MycompanyMainBundle:Image'
    image_manager.class:               Mycompany\MainBundle\Service\Image\ImageManager
    image_manipulator.class:           Mycompany\MainBundle\Service\Image\ImageManipulator

services:
    image_manager:
        class: %image_manager.class%
        arguments:
          - @image_manipulator
          - @image_repository

    image_repository:
        class:           %image_repository.class%
        factory_service: doctrine.odm.mongodb
        factory_method:  getRepository
        arguments:
            - %image_repository.factory_argument%

    image_manipulator:
        class: %image_manipulator.class%
```

Comment: *DEPRECATION WARNING*: No more factory_service and factory_method since Symfony 2.6

Comment: There won't be any Default factories but Symfony 3.4 supports a way to create your own factories.

Answer (score 107):

Here is a cleaned up solution for those coming from Google like me:

**Update:** here is the Symfony 2.6 (and up) solution:

```
services:

    myrepository:
        class: Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
        factory: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", getRepository]
        arguments:
            - MyBundle\Entity\MyClass

    myservice:
        class: MyBundle\Service\MyService
        arguments:
            - "@myrepository"
```

---

**Deprecated** solution (Symfony 2.5 and less):

```
services:

    myrepository:
        class: Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
        factory_service: doctrine.orm.entity_manager
        factory_method: getRepository
        arguments:
            - MyBundle\Entity\MyClass

    myservice:
        class: MyBundle\Service\MyService
        arguments:
            - "@myrepository"
```

Comment: While using MongoDB, use `doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager` as factory_service

Comment: This works which is awesome but it makes any repositories you add in this way accessible through controllers with `$this->get('myrepository')`. Is there any way to define/pass the repository as an argument to `myservice` without having to define it as a service itself?

Comment: @Andy you can define services as `private`, which means they can be injected (in YAML config) but not fetched using `->get()`

Comment: **DEPRECATION WARNING:** No more `factory_service` and `factory_method` since **Symfony 2.6**. This is how it should be done now: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31807608/828366

Comment: @FrancescoCasula thank you, I've updated the answer :)

Comment: Note that since Symfony **3.0**, you should use quotes for [some YAML configurations](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-3.0.md#yaml). So here you should use `factory: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", getRepository]`, otherwise you'll be greeted by a pretty ParseException.

Comment: PhpStorm complains - "Expect instance of 'Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface" .  Symfony 3.4

Answer (score 42):

In case if do not want to define each repository as a service, starting from version `2.4` you can do following, (`default` is a name of the entity manager):

```
@=service('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager').getRepository('MycompanyMainBundle:Image')
```

Comment: How would this look in an XML services files?

Comment: This is based on the expression component: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#using-the-expression-language

Comment: Using Symfony 2.7, I was able to get the repository with shorter syntax:
`@=service('doctrine').getRepository('AppBundle:EntityX')`

Comment: This is perfectly translated as "$this->get("doctrine")->getRepository("AppBundle:EntityX")" in *Container.php", love this shortcut!

Comment: @Jonny here's the xml version:`<service id="image_manager" class="MyCompany\MainBundle\ImageManager">
    <argument type="expression">service('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager').getRepository('MycompanyMainBundle:Image')</argument>
</service>`

Comment: so for injected specific arguments: it would be $orderRepository: "@=service('doctrine').getRepository('App:Order')" and composer require symfony/expression-language

Answer (score 20):

## Symfony 3.3, 4 and 5 makes this much simpler.

**Check my post [How to use Repository with Doctrine as Service in Symfony](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/10/16/how-to-use-repository-with-doctrine-as-service-in-symfony/)** for more general description.

To your code, all you need to do is use *composition over inheritance* - one of SOLID patterns.

#### 1. Create own repository without direct dependency on Doctrine

```
<?php

namespace MycompanyMainBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use MycompanyMainBundle\Entity\Image;

class ImageRepository
{
    private $repository;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->repository = $entityManager->getRepository(Image::class);
    }

    // add desired methods here
    public function findAll()
    {
        return $this->repository->findAll();
    }
}
```

#### 2. Add config registration with [PSR-4 based autoregistration](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/05/07/how-to-refactor-to-new-dependency-injection-features-in-symfony-3-3/#4-use-psr-4-based-service-autodiscovery-and-registration)

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true

    MycompanyMainBundle\:
        resource: ../../src/MycompanyMainBundle
```

#### 3. Now you can add any dependency anywhere via constructor injection

```
use MycompanyMainBundle\Repository\ImageRepository;

class ImageService
{
    public function __construct(ImageRepository $imageRepository)
    {
        $this->imageRepository = $imageRepository;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this still up-to-date for Symfony 4.1 ?

Comment: Yes, construction injection mechanics should not change up to Symfony 5. What troubles do you have?

Comment: I created a service in Service Folder called UserManager and wanna use my UsersRepository there "class UsersRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository"

Comment: That's a different approach I'm advocating against in the post. It's create huge vendor lock of almost all your database-related entry services to Symfony and Doctrine at once. See the post for more

Answer (score 0):

In my case bases upon @Tomáš Votruba answer and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52676915/4706711) I propose the following approaches:

## Adapter Approach

### Without Inheritance

1. Create a generic Adapter Class:

   ```
   namespace AppBundle\Services;
   use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

   class RepositoryServiceAdapter
   {
       private $repository=null;

       /**
       * @param EntityManagerInterface the Doctrine entity Manager
       * @param String $entityName The name of the entity that we will retrieve the repository
       */
       public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,$entityName)
       {
           $this->repository=$entityManager->getRepository($entityName)
       }

       public function __call($name,$arguments)
       {
         if(empty($arrguments)){ //No arguments has been passed
           $this->repository->$name();
         } else {
           //@todo: figure out how to pass the parameters
           $this->repository->$name(...$argument);
         }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Then foreach entity Define a service, for examplein my case to define a (I use php to define symfony services):

   ```
    $container->register('ellakcy.db.contact_email',AppBundle\Services\Adapters\RepositoryServiceAdapter::class)
     ->serArguments([new Reference('doctrine'),AppBundle\Entity\ContactEmail::class]);
   ```

### With Inheritance

1. Same step 1 mentioned above
2. Extend the `RepositoryServiceAdapter` class for example:

   ```
   namespace AppBundle\Service\Adapters;

   use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
   use AppBundle\Entity\ContactEmail;

   class ContactEmailRepositoryServiceAdapter extends RepositoryServiceAdapter
   {
     public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
     {
       parent::__construct($entityManager,ContactEmail::class);
     }
   }
   ```
3. Register service:

   ```
   $container->register('ellakcy.db.contact_email',AppBundle\Services\Adapters\RepositoryServiceAdapter::class)
     ->serArguments([new Reference('doctrine')]);
   ```

Either the case you have a good testable way to function tests your database beavior also it aids you on mocking in case you want to unit test your service without the need to worry too much on how to do that. For example, let us suppose we have the following service:

```
//Namespace definitions etc etc

class MyDummyService
{
  public function __construct(RepositoryServiceAdapter $adapter)
  {
    //Do stuff
  }
}
```

And the RepositoryServiceAdapter adapts the following repository:

```
//Namespace definitions etc etc

class SomeRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
   public function search($params)
   {
     //Search Logic
   }
}
```

### Testing

So you can easily mock/hardcode/emulate the behavior of the method `search` defined in `SomeRepository` by mocking aither the `RepositoryServiceAdapter` in non-inheritance approach or the `ContactEmailRepositoryServiceAdapter` in the inheritance one.

## The Factory Approach

Alternatively you can define the following factory:

```
namespace AppBundle\ServiceFactories;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class RepositoryFactory
{
  /**
  * @param EntityManagerInterface $entityManager The doctrine entity Manager
  * @param String $entityName The name of the entity
  * @return Class
  */
  public static function repositoryAsAService(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,$entityName)
  {
    return $entityManager->getRepository($entityName);
  }
}
```

And then Switch to php service annotation by doing the following:

Place this into a file `./app/config/services.php` (for symfony v3.4, `.` is assumed your ptoject's root)

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;
$definition = new Definition();

$definition->setAutowired(true)->setAutoconfigured(true)->setPublic(false);

// $this is a reference to the current loader
$this->registerClasses($definition, 'AppBundle\\', '../../src/AppBundle/*', '../../src/AppBundle/{Entity,Repository,Tests,Interfaces,Services/Adapters/RepositoryServiceAdapter.php}');


$definition->addTag('controller.service_arguments');
$this->registerClasses($definition, 'AppBundle\\Controller\\', '../../src/AppBundle/Controller/*');
```

And cange the `./app/config/config.yml` (`.` is assumed your ptoject's root)

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    #Replace services.yml to services.php
    - { resource: services.php }

#Other Configuration
```

Then you can clace the service as follows (used from my example where I used a Dummy entity named `Item`):

```
$container->register(ItemRepository::class,ItemRepository::class)
  ->setFactory([new Reference(RepositoryFactory::class),'repositoryAsAService'])
  ->setArguments(['$entityManager'=>new Reference('doctrine.orm.entity_manager'),'$entityName'=>Item::class]);
```

Also as a generic tip, switching to `php` service annotation allows you to do trouble-free more advanced service configuration thin one above. For code snippets use a special [repository](https://github.com/pc-magas/symfony-repository-as-a-service) I made using the `factory` method.

Comment: Can you explain **why** you propose that? Compared to a raw solution, you loose auto-completion help from your IDE - and what do you gain?

Answer (score 0):

For Symfony 5 it is really simple, without need of services.yml to inject the dependency:

1. inject the Entity Manager in the service constructor

> ```
> private $em;
>
> public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
> {
>     $this->em = $em;
> }
> ```

2. Then get the repository :

> $this->em->getRepository(ClassName::class)

by replacing ClassName with your entity name.

Comment: While this works, it's the wrong approach, you should inject your Repository and not get it via the EntityManager as this breaks proper DI.