# symfony2 custom repository extending EntityRepository

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I am trying to implement a custom repository class in symfony2, and I want it to extend `EntityRepository` class. I am having trouble with passing the getting arguments to the parent (i.e. `EntityRepository`) constructor. This is the signiture of parent constructor:

```
public function __construct($em, Mapping\ClassMetadata $class)
```

So I had to add this to my `services.yml` file, in order to get the arguments:

```
parameters:
    user_provider.class: Untitled\F5Bundle\Security\UserRepository

services:
    user_meta_data:
        class: Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetaData
        arguments:
            name: "Untitled\F5Bundle\Entity\User"
    user_provider:
        class: "%user_provider.class%"
        arguments:
            entityManager: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
            meta_data: "@user_meta_data"
```

And I also added the annotation tag to my `User` class (which I'm not sure if it was neccessary)

Now when I run it, it raises an error. the message says:

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetaData' not found
in /mnt/data/Projects/F5/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 2749
```

(`/mnt/data/Projects/F5/` is where I keep the code)

I don't get it. What's wrong here? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metadata is obtained with the MetadataFactory. As an example you can see how it works in EntityManager.

```
public function getClassMetadata($className)
{
    return $this->metadataFactory->getMetadataFor($className);
}
```

You can retrieve you repository as service as well. Look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12223176/how-to-inject-a-repository-into-a-service-in-symfony2).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to inject these constructor arguments yourself, just specify which repository class you want to use:

```
/**
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="MyProject\UserRepository")
 */
class User
{
    ...
}
```

See also http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#entity

Answer (score 0):

You miss typed classname "ClassMetaData" should be **ClassMetadata**

```
class: Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata
```