# Symfony 2: Creating a service from a Repository

Tags: symfony, service, doctrine-orm, repository

I'm learning Symfony and I've been trying to create a service, using a repository.
I've created my repositories and entities from generate:entity, so they should be fine.

So far what I got in my services.yml is:

```
parameters:
    mytest.entity: TestTestBundle:Brand
    mytest.class:  Test\TestBundle\Entity\Brand
    default_repository.class: Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository

services:
     myservice:
          class: %default_repository.class%
          factory-service: doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager
          factory-method: getRepository
          arguments:
            - %mytest.entity%
```

But when I try to call the service, I get this error:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 2 passed to Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata, none given, called in
```

Then I tried to create the service just using an entity. My services.yml would look like:

```
services:
     myservice:
          class: %mytest.class%
          factory-service: doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager
          factory-method: getRepository
          arguments:
            - %mytest.entity%
```

But for this, I get:

```
Error: Call to undefined method 
                Test\TestBundle\Entity\Brand::findAll
```

Does anybody know what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here is how we did it  in KnpRadBundle: https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpRadBundle/blob/develop/DependencyInjection/Definition/DoctrineRepositoryFactory.php#L9

Finally it should be:

```
my_service:
    class: Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectRepository
    factory_service: doctrine # this is an instance of Registry
    factory_method: getRepository
    arguments: [ %mytest.entity% ]
```

**UPDATE**

Since 2.4, doctrine allows to override the default repositor factory.

Here is a possible way to implement it in symfony: https://gist.github.com/docteurklein/9778800

Comment: Thanks,

If Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectRepository, how can you instantiate it?

factory-service: doctrine # this is an instance of Registry
you mean, it is doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager  ?

Comment: no it's an implementation of https://github.com/doctrine/common/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/ManagerRegistry.php . You could do the same with an EntityManager instance. And in fact, the `class: ` is not important here, because it's a **factory** service, the container does not instanciate the given class itself but asks a services's method to do it.

Comment: but the `class: Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectRepository` is not wrong neither, because the returned instance is indeed an implementation of an ObjectRepository interface

Comment: Thanks Florian.

No, it does not, or I'm doing something wrong, but as I said:

FatalErrorException: Error: Cannot instantiate interface Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectRepository in

Comment: Can you paste the result of your service dump (located in `app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php`) ? The method should be named: `getMyserviceService` (based on your example).

Comment: Thanks Florian:

    protected function getMyserviceService()
    {
        return $this->services['myservice'] = new \Test\TestBundle\Entity\Repository\BrandRepository('TestTestBundle:Brand');
    }

Comment: and you service definition ?

Comment: HAHA! I got it I think :) it should be `factory_service` and not `factory-service`. note the `_`.

Comment: I'm ashamed and I just can't say thank you enough! I was about to give up. Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 44):

**DEPRECATION WARNING:** No more `factory_service` and `factory_method`. This is how you should do it since **Symfony 2.6** (for **Symfony 3.3+** check below):

```
parameters:
    entity.my_entity: "AppBundle:MyEntity"

services:
    my_entity_repository:
        class: AppBundle\Repository\MyEntityRepository
        factory: ["@doctrine", getRepository]
        arguments:
            - %entity.my_entity%
```

> The new [setFactory()](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Definition.html#method_setFactory) method was introduced in Symfony 2.6. Refer to older versions for the syntax for factories prior to 2.6.

http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/service_container/factories.html

**EDIT:** Looks like they keep changing this, so since **Symfony 3.3** there's a new syntax:

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    # ...

    AppBundle\Email\NewsletterManager:
        # call the static method
        factory: ['AppBundle\Email\NewsletterManagerStaticFactory', createNewsletterManager]
```

Check it out: http://symfony.com/doc/3.3/service_container/factories.html

Comment: This works nice, tnx. But I would like to get one more step further: what if I also want to inject a service into this repository (let's say a Paginator service)? I tried adding more params to it, but that doesn't work, since Symfony is not "expecting" any of those I give it.

Comment: @userfuser did you try overriding the constructor? You can add all the new dependencies there, just remember to call `parent::__construct($arg)` to provide what Doctrine expects as well.

Comment: @FrancescoCasula I did think of it, but I wasn't yet ready to make it a global change for all the repos, since this injection was needed only in few cases. Eventually, I did it for this specific case by using a setter injection, like defined in the docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/injection_types.html#setter-injection

Answer (score 10):

You may have used the wrong YAML-Keys. Your first configuration works fine for me using

- factory_service instead of factory-service
- factory_method instead of factory-method

Comment: That's quite useful for me, thank you. I also found [some related note posted on Dec'2012](http://www.phamviet.net/2012/12/09/symfony-2-inject-service-as-dependency-in-to-repository/) - I'll leave link here, just in case someone is also looking for something like that.

Answer (score 2):

**Since 2017 and Symfony 3.3+** this is now much easier.

*Note: Try to avoid generic commands like `generate:entity`. They are desined for begginers to make project work fast. They tend to bare bad practises and take very long time to change.*

**Check my post [How to use Repository with Doctrine as Service in Symfony](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/10/16/how-to-use-repository-with-doctrine-as-service-in-symfony/)** for more general description.

To your code:

#### 1. Update your config registration to use [PSR-4 based autoregistration](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/05/07/how-to-refactor-to-new-dependency-injection-features-in-symfony-3-3/#4-use-psr-4-based-service-autodiscovery-and-registration)

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true

    Test\TestBundle\:
        resource: ../../src/Test/TestBundle
```

#### 2. Composition over Inheritance - Create own repository without direct dependency on Doctrine

```
<?php

namespace Test\TestBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class BrandRepository
{
    private $repository;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->repository = $entityManager->getRepository(Brand::class);
    }

    public function findAll()
    {
        return $this->repository->findAll();
    }
}
```

#### 3. Use in any Service or Controller via constructor injection

```
use Test\TestBundle\Repository\BrandRepository;

class MyController
{
    /**
     * @var BrandRepository
     */
    private $brandRepository;

    public function __construct(BrandRepository $brandRepository)
    {
        $this->brandRepository = $brandRepository;
    }

    public function someAction()
    {
        $allBrands = $this->brandRepository->findAll();
        // ...
    }

}
```

Comment: This does instantiate a service with autowiring, but the service is not the repository itself, which doesn't solve the question.  I _think_ the original configuration will work with autowiring by renaming the service to `Test\TestBundle\Entity\Brand`, removing the `class`, `factory_service`, and `factory_method` configurations, and adding `factory: 'Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface:getRepository'`.  And maybe quote wrapping the argument.  I still have a lot of refactoring on a current project with similar configurations, so I can't yet say absolutely, but I at least get the cache to clear.

Comment: One other thing - I'm also defining `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface: { alias: doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager }`

Answer (score 0):

I convert service.yml to service.xml, and update DependencyInjection Extension, everything is working for me. I don't know why, but yml config will thrown Catchable Fatal Error. You can try using xml config for service config.

service.yml:

```
services:
    acme.demo.apikey_userprovider:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\UserinfoRepository
        factory-service: doctrine.orm.entity_manager
        factory-method: getRepository
        arguments: [ AcmeDemoBundle:Userinfo ]

    acme.demo.apikey_authenticator:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\Security\ApiKeyAuthenticator
        arguments: [ "@acme.demo.apikey_userprovider" ]
```

service.xml:

```
<services>
    <service id="acme.demo.apikey_userprovider" class="Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\UserinfoRepository"  factory-service="doctrine.orm.entity_manager" factory-method="getRepository">
        <argument>AcmeDemoBundle:Userinfo</argument>
    </service>

    <service id="acme.demo.apikey_authenticator" class="Acme\DemoBundle\Security\ApiKeyAuthenticator">
        <argument type="service" id="acme.demo.apikey_userprovider" />
    </service>
</services>
```

Comment: your yml keys are wrong, this `factory-service` should be `factory_service` (underscore).

Answer (score 0):

**Symfony 3.3** and **doctrine-bundle 1.8** there is a **Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ContainerRepositoryFactory**
which helps to create repository as service.

#### Example

What we want

```
$rep = $kernel->getContainer()
    ->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')
    ->getRepository(Brand::class);
```

ORM description

```
# Brand.orm.yaml
...
repositoryClass: App\Repository\BrandRepository
...
```

Service description

```
# service.yaml

App\Repository\BrandRepository:
    arguments:
      - '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager'
      - '@=service("doctrine.orm.entity_manager").getClassMetadata("App\\Entity\\Brand")'
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.repository_service }
    calls:
        - method: setDefaultLocale
          arguments:
              - '%kernel.default_locale%'
        - method: setRequestStack
          arguments:
              - '@request_stack'
```

Answer (score -2):

sf 2.6+

```
parameters:
    mytest.entity: TestTestBundle:Brand
    mytest.class:  Test\TestBundle\Entity\Brand
    default_repository.class: Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository

services:
     myservice:
          class: %default_repository.class%
          factory: ["@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager", "getRepository"]
          arguments:
            - %mytest.entity%
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I think it would be appreciated if you could add some explanation why this solves the problem.

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/2.6/components/dependency_injection/factories.html
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition::setFactoryMethod(getRepository) is deprecated since version 2.6 and will be removed in 3.0. Use Definition::setFactory()