# Can I use an entity from a different Bundle without breaking SoC?

Tags: php, symfony, service, dependency-injection, doctrine-orm

My example application has two bundles, `AcmeAuthenticationBundle` and `AcmePhonelistbundle`.

In `AcmeAuthenticationBundle` I created a user entity which I need for authentication (obviously) that has some user specific attributes (like surname, givename, etc.). In `AcmePhonelistBundle` I want to generate a phonelist based on that user entity.

For this purpose I created a service that gets the doctrine entity manager and the user class (in doctrine shorthand form) injected (defined in services.yml):

```
parameters:
    acme_phonelist.user.class: AcmeAuthenticationBundle:User

services:
    acme_phonelist.factory:
        class: Acme\PhonelistBundle\Factory\PhonelistFactory
        arguments:
            em: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
            userClass: "%acme_phonelist.user.class%"
```

I couldn't come up with a different/better solution to keep those bundles decoupled. Is this a proper/sane way for this use case or did I overlook something? Any suggestions for improvement?

Comment: @Touki Kind of, but I want to keep it loosely coupled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a bundle or a service with the sole purpose of containing user-specific data, and reuse it in both the phonelist and the authenticationbundle.

Comment: After having implemented your proposed solution I found out that I can use doctrine repositories as services (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17228417/symfony-2-creating-a-service-from-a-repository).