# Doctrine2 many repositories for the same entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, repository, entity

For specific needs, I have to create 2 repositories for the same Entity.
The first repository are in the same bundle with the entity and the second, I have to create it in an other bundle but i want to use the same entity with different methodes.

Any idea how can I do that ?

Comment: create a repository that extends from another ?

Comment: No, it not what I need to do. Because each repositories extends from an other repositories.

Comment: Use a different entity manager for each bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Can't say I see the point, but try this: [Symfony 2: Creating a service from a Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17228417/symfony-2-creating-a-service-from-a-repository)

Create 2 services which extend `EntityRepository`, construct them correctly and give them the entity reference.

Obviously `$em->getRepository('Entity')` won't work.
But `$this->container->get('repository_service_1')` will.

Why do you need this?