# Call service into EntityRepository

Tags: symfony

how I can call a service in this EntityRepository

```
class CityRepository extends EntityRepository{

   public function guessCity($name){
    // ..... call service
   }
}
```

this is my service

```
namespace Project\ManagmentBundle\Services;

class FormatString {

public function replaceAccents($str)
{ 
  .....
}
```

services.yml

```
services:
project.format_string:
  class: Project\ManagmentBundle\Services\FormatString
```

Comment: you shouldn't be doing logic in the storage layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't do this. Rather you should call repository from your service.

IMO passing any container service to repository is bad practice.

But if you really need to do that, then you can register your repository as a service, and then inject other service to it. Here is nice answer for that case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17230333/919567

Answer (score 1):

**Since 2017 and Symfony 3.3+**, you can do this easily with **service pattern**.

**Passing service to repository is not bad practise**, it was just so complicated that it would create really messy code, if you'd try to do so.

**Check my post [How to use Repository with Doctrine as Service in Symfony](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/10/16/how-to-use-repository-with-doctrine-as-service-in-symfony/)** for more general description.

To your code:

#### 1. Remove direct dependency on Doctrine from your Repository

```
namespace Project\ManagmentBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class CityRepository
{
    private $repository;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->repository = $entityManager->getRepository(City::class);
    }

    public function guessCity($name)
    {
        return $this->repository->findBy([ 
            'name' => $name // improve logic with LIKE %...% etc.
        ]);
    }
}
```

#### 2. Register services with autowiring

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true

    Project\ManagmentBundle\:
       resource: ../../src/ManagmentBundle
```

#### 3. Adding any service to repository is now easy

```
<?php

use Project\ManagmentBundle\Services\FormatString;

class CityRepository
{
    private $repository;

    private $formatString;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, FormatString $formatString)
    {
        $this->repository = $entityManager->getRepository(City::class);
        $this->formatString = $formatString;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, Tomáš. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I'm glad it works :) In that case, you might find this one useful too: https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2018/01/08/clean-and-decoupled-controllers-commands-and-event-subscribers-once-and-for-all-with-delegator-pattern/