# Symfony FOS OAuth with custom User

Tags: php, symfony, oauth, oauth-2.0, fosoauthserverbundle

How is it possible to implement an OAuth server based on FOSOAuthServerBundle without using FOSUserBundle?

My user class starts like his:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
*
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="user")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
*/
class User implements UserInterface
```

My user repository class starts with this:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User\UserLoaderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException;

class UserRepository extends EntityRepository implements UserLoaderInterface, UserProviderInterface
```

In my security.yml I included the following:

```
    providers:
        user_db:
            entity:
                class: AppBundle\Entity\User
                property: username
```

And finally the config.yml:

```
fos_oauth_server:
    db_driver: orm
    client_class: AppBundle\Entity\OAuthClient
    access_token_class: AppBundle\Entity\OAuthAccessToken
    refresh_token_class: AppBundle\Entity\OAuthRefreshToken
    auth_code_class: AppBundle\Entity\OAuthAuthCode
    service:
        options:
            access_token_lifetime: 3600

        user_provider: user_db
        #user_provider: AppBundle\Entity\UserRepository
        #user_provider: AppBundle\Entity\User
```

Right now it throws an exception:

```
[1] Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to a member function loadUserByUsername() on null
    at n/a
        in /home/wanderson/api/vendor/friendsofsymfony/oauth-server-bundle/Storage/OAuthStorage.php line 161

    at FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Storage\OAuthStorage->checkUserCredentials(object(OAuthClient), 'admin', 'admin')
        in /home/wanderson/api/vendor/friendsofsymfony/oauth2-php/lib/OAuth2.php line 929

    at OAuth2\OAuth2->grantAccessTokenUserCredentials(object(OAuthClient), array('grant_type' => 'password', 'scope' => null, 'code' => null, 'redirect_uri' => null, 'username' => 'admin', 'password' => 'admin', 'refresh_token' => null))
        in /home/wanderson/api/vendor/friendsofsymfony/oauth2-php/lib/OAuth2.php line 815

    at OAuth2\OAuth2->grantAccessToken(object(Request))
        in /home/wanderson/api/vendor/friendsofsymfony/oauth-server-bundle/Controller/TokenController.php line 42

    at FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Controller\TokenController->tokenAction(object(Request))
        in  line 

    at call_user_func_array(array(object(TokenController), 'tokenAction'), array(object(Request)))
        in /home/wanderson/api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php line 153

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), '1')
        in /home/wanderson/api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php line 68

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
        in /home/wanderson/api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php line 169

    at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
        in /home/wanderson/api/web/app_dev.php line 30

    at require('/home/wanderson/api/web/app_dev.php')
        in /home/wanderson/api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/router_dev.php line 40
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a user provider, or if you want to use your repository class for it read 'how define repository like service' (i don't know working if it at newest version or not):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17230333/6848076 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31807608/6848076

But i not recommended this way

```
<?php 

namespace AppBundle\Security\Provider\UserProvider;

use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Exception\UnsupportedException;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class UserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    protected $class;

    protected $userRepository;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager, $class)
    {
        $this->class = $class;
        $this->userRepository = $entityManager->getRepository($class);
    }

    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        $user = $this->userRepository->findOneBy(array('username' => $username));
        if (null === $user) {
            $message = sprintf(
                'Unable to find an active User object identified by "%s"',
                $username
            );
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException($message, 0, $failed);
        }
        return $user;
    }

    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        $class = get_class($user);
        if (false == $this->supportsClass($class)) {
            throw new UnsupportedException(
                sprintf(
                    'Instances of "%s" are not supported',
                    $class
                )
            );
        }
        return $this->userRepository->find($user->getId());
    }

    public function supportsClass($class)
    {
        return $this->class === $class
            || is_subclass_of($class, $this->class);

    }
}
```

About services you can read: http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html
Define a provider service at {project_directory}/src/AppBundle/Resources/config/service.yml

```
parameters:
    user.class: AppBundle\Entity\User
    user.provider.class: AppBundle\Security\Provider\UserProvider
services:
    user.provider:
      class: %user.provider.class%
      arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager, %user.class%]
```

Change fosoauth configuration at config.yml:

```
fos_oauth_server:
    db_driver: orm
    client_class: AppBundle\Entity\OAuthClient
    access_token_class: AppBundle\Entity\OAuthAccessToken
    refresh_token_class: AppBundle\Entity\OAuthRefreshToken
    auth_code_class: AppBundle\Entity\OAuthAuthCode
    service:
        options:
            access_token_lifetime: 3600
        user_provider: user.provider
```

About security.yml you can read: http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html

Comment: Sorry, I am a newbie with Symfony, I'm not sure where do place this provider service configuration. I tried to put it under security.providers (security.yml) exactly as in your example and I get Symfony to tell me this file does not contain valid YAML. PS: the `UserProvider` class is, except for the constructor, pretty much identical to my `UserRepository` class.