# PHP Symfony Framework Setter Injection with Doctrine

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

I have the following settings in `service.yml`

```
  appbundle.entity.countryrepository:
    class: AppBundle\Repository\CountryRepository
    calls:
      - [setPagination, ['@knp_paginator']]
```

code in controller is:

```
$countryRepository = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Country');
```

When the object is created, `setPagination()` is never called?

What can be the reason/faults?

Comment: Because $em->getRepository has no idea that the container even exists.  Adjust your service definition to use a factory to create the repository (search for examples for the syntax) and then access the repository using $this->get('appbundle.entity.countryrepository');

Comment: You are doing it wrong. You can't define a repository as a service this way. Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17228417/symfony-2-creating-a-service-from-a-repository

Comment: Thank you Cerad and Denis. I used a factory to create the repository and used the controller get function as explained in your comment.