# Symfony3 - inject a repository into a service with MongoDB ORM

Tags: mongodb, service, dependency-injection, symfony

i read the post on injecting repository into a service under Symfony2[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12223176/how-to-inject-a-repository-into-a-service-in-symfony2/25598717#25598717?newreg=4053385aa1d741f5a5af785d6ef6ff16). I am trying since two days to adapt my code and I turning around.

I need your help.

So what is the problem :

I am adapting the bundle "RatingStar" (http://www.tipocode.com/symfony-2/symfony2-star-rating-system/) in Symfony3 and MongoDB.

I want use my mongodb in place doctrine (mysql) and i am lost :(

**There is a service :**

```
  starbar.twig_extension: 
    class: PortailBundle\Twig\StarBarExtension
    arguments: [ "@doctrine", "@request_stack" ]
    tags: 
      - 
        name: twig.extension
```

Note : i try to substitue "@doctrine" by factory... and so on but i have some errors in my class in the arguments list.

**There is a class  like this :**

```
class StarBarExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    protected $doctrine; 
    private $RequestStack;


    public function __construct(RegistryInterface $doctrine, RequestStack $RequestStack)
    {
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
        $this->requestStack = $RequestStack;
    }

    public function getFunctions() {
      return array(
           'starBar' => new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'myStarBar'),
      );
    }

    public function myStarBar($numStar, $mediaId, $starWidth) {

    $cookies = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->cookies->get('LilmodLemaedNote'.$mediaId);

    $nbrPixelsInDiv = $numStar * $starWidth; // Calculate the DIV width in pixel

    **$query = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getRepository('PortailBundle:Notes')->findOneBy(array('ARTICLE' =>$mediaId));**
```

I follow a lot of example but without success. I don't know what i do with the service and what i have to declare in the class to use my query.

Please try to help me.

Answer (score 0):

You have no `$this->get('doctrine_mongodb')` because you not injected `container`. But what you do in that line of code, you getting a service called `doctrine_mongodb`, and this is yours needed service, so in `services.yml`:

```
arguments: [ "@doctrine_mongodb", "@request_stack" ]
```

and in your `StarBarExtension` class:

```
$query = $this->doctrine->getRepository('PortailBundle:Notes')->findOneBy(array('ARTICLE' =>$mediaId));
```

Remove `RegistryInterface` from your constructor as well.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you are right.

I change the service.yml like this :

```
starbar.twig_extension: 
    class: PortailBundle\Twig\StarBarExtension
    arguments: [ "@doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager", "@request_stack" ]
    tags: 
      - 
        name: twig.extension
```

and in the class StarBarExtension :

```
namespace PortailBundle\Twig;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentManager;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;

  class StarBarExtension extends \Twig_Extension
    {
      protected $doctrine;
      private $RequestStack;


 public function __construct(DocumentManager $doctrine, RequestStack $RequestStack)
{
    $this->doctrine_mongodb = $doctrine;
    $this->requestStack = $RequestStack;
}

public function getFunctions() {
  return array(
       'starBar' => new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'myStarBar'),
  );
}

public function myStarBar($numStar, $mediaId, $starWidth) {

$cookies = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->cookies->get('LilmodLemaedNote'.$mediaId);

$query = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getRepository('PortailBundle:Notes')->findOneBy(array('ARTICLE' =>$mediaId));
```

and the result is :

```
Attempted to call an undefined method named "get" of class "PortailBundle\Twig\StarBarExtension".
Did you mean to call e.g. "getFilters", "getFunctions", "getGlobals", "getName", "getNodeVisitors", "getOperators", "getTests" or "getTokenParsers"?
```

I think, it is normal, but how to be able to launch the request ?

---------- **i found a solution**

I don't know if it is the good way but i have the request :

just change

```
$query = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getRepository('PortailBundle:Notes')->findOneBy(array('ARTICLE' =>$mediaId));
```

into

```
$query = $this->doctrine_mongodb->getRepository('PortailBundle:Notes')->findOneBy(array('ARTICLE' =>$mediaId));
```

bye