# Adapting a class Using php's __call method: Passing the parameters

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.4

Based upon [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46862838/4706711) on my Symfony 3.4 project I thought of using the magic `__call` method in order to have a common way to invoke repositories as a service:

```
namespace AppBundle\Services;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class RepositoryServiceAdapter
{
        private $repository=null;

        /**
        * @param EntityManagerInterface the Doctrine entity Manager
        * @param String $entityName The name of the entity that we will retrieve the repository
        */
        public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,$entityName)
        {
            $this->repository=$entityManager->getRepository($entityName)
        }

        public function __call($name,$arguments)
        {     
          if(empty($arguments)){ //No arguments has been passed
             $this->repository->$name();
          } else {
             //@todo: figure out how to pass the parameters
             $this->repository->$name();
          }
        }
}
```

But I got stuck to this problem:

A repository method will have this form:

```
public function aMethod($param1,$param2)
{
  //Some magic is done here
}
```

So I will need somehow to iterate the array `$arguments` in order to pass the parameters to the function if I knew exactly what method would be called I would arbitatily pass the parameters, for example if I knew that a method had 3 parameters I would use:

```
        public function __call($name,$arguments)
        {
           $this->repository->$name($argument[0],$argument[1],$argument[2]);
        }
```

But that seems impractical and not a concrete solution for me because a method can have more than 1 parameters. I think I need to solve the following problems:

1. How I will find out how many parameters a method has?
2. How to pass the arguments while iterating the array `$arguments`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of PHP 5.6 you have [argument unpacking](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat) which allows you to do exactly what your after using `...`, so

```
$this->repository->$name($argument[0],$argument[1],$argument[2]);
```

becomes...

```
$this->repository->$name(...$argument);
```

This will pass any number or arguments as though they are individual fields.